# Free Commercial use text editor

Tags: html, editor

I'm looking for an online text-editor just like CKEDITOR which is free even for commercial usage.

Do you know any one them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/support/faq/open%20source#question5 ckeditor IS free for commercial use.

Comment: wow, didn't see that, I looked at their website, and I saw that it cost 300$. that's weird.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)
2. [FCKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
3. [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/)
4. [BXE](http://www.bitfluxeditor.org)
5. [MarkItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)
6. [WidgEditor](https://code.google.com/p/widgeditor/)
7. [EDITArea](http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/)
8. [Cross Browser Rich Text Editor (RTE)](http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/)
9. [YUI Library Rich Text Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)
10. [FreeTextBox](http://www.freetextbox.com/)
11. [Damn Small Rich Text Editor](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/WYSIWYG-Editors/Damn-Small-Rich-Text-Editor-43997.html)
12. [Silverlight Rich Text Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426926%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
13. [Dijit.Editor](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Editor.html)
14. [WYMeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/)
15. [Whizzywig](http://unverse.net/Whizzywig-web-based-rich-text-editor)
16. [openWYSIWYG](https://drupal.org/project/openwysiwyg)
17. [XStandard](http://www.xstandard.com/)
18. [Xinha](http://trac.xinha.org/)

Hope you find one that suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This article lists open source editors for you. [Link](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/)

If still you are not satisfied then search for "open source text editor for websites" on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=open+source+text+editor&oq=open+source+text+editor&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.6582j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=86759f64f0dd43f0&q=open+source+text+editor+for+websites)